# How do I set the system clock in Rust?

Tags: linux, rust, real-time-clock

For ham radio field day, I have a GPS dongle that I want to use to set my Linux laptop’s system time when I’m in the outback, where there’s no Internet access.

How do you set the system clock time in Rust?

PS: I checked [crates.io](https://crates.io/) but nothing stood out to me as a solution.

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-set-linux-system-time/31960

Comment: For some ham radio digital modes like FT8, it’s critical to have a correct system time. My laptop’s clock will probably still be correct once it’s offline and in the field, but I’d still like to try the experiment of setting the clock from a GPS input.

Comment: In _any_ language that isn't C, if there isn't a native implementation, then what you do is find the C library function (or syscall, or whatnot as the case may be) and use that via interop. It's no different for Rust.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Given how difficult it is to safely wrap a C library in Rust, this is pretty bad advice.

Comment: Pretty sure ntpd can use GPS dongle as a time source and will do a better job you'd make in reasonable amount of time. Are you sure you want to implement that yourself?

Comment: @Caesar, ... Agreed, but using a library someone else wrapped is supposed to be better? It's all C (or at least, syscalls and ioctls via a C-centric stack layout and calling interface) in the end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Better in several regards 1. If you don't trust that "somebody else" to do it correctly, you can review their code. Nobody will review yours. 2. Nix is widely used, so you can get some additional confidence that at least the struct, if not the function declarations are correct. 3. The people who made nix have "some" experience with what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks less of a "I want to write a solid library" and more like a "hack it together" kind of thing, a few options, some hacky:

- You could just shell out to coreutils' `date`:

  ```
  std::process::Command::new("date")
      // Produce the date string with some crate: date, chrono, hifitime, ...
      .args(["--set", "2023-12-14 01:23:45.678"])
      .env_clear()
      .env("LC_ALL", "C.UTF-8")
      .output()
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2762984826e206ad0ef3d39983547544)
  (See comments about accuracy!)
- You could run `date` with `strace` and see that it uses the `clock_settime` syscall. Usually, you can find a [safe and nicely typed wrapped version](https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/time/fn.clock_settime.html) of that syscall in the `nix` crate. If you can't find it, [check `libc`](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/libc/fn.clock_settime.html).
- There is a rust reimplementation of coreutils (turns up in a [search](https://lib.rs/search?q=set+date+time) too), you could [check what that does](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/blob/60fbf1db84421405c6e7c84db5489dd2b293c622/src/uu/date/src/date.rs#L439-L452).

All of these of course require the appropriate permission, of course, either being root or having a capability set.

---

Side note: I wholeheartedly agree with @n0rd's comment. I don't know how you're reading from your gps dongle, but if it's already gpsd there's no point, and if it's some lower-level method, I assume you'll run into fun problems ([Week number rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_week_number_rollover) comes to mind).

Comment: Going through an execve takes a lot of time (and rounding to seconds loses a lot of precision) compared to the level of accuracy that GPS provides

Comment: Ah, GPS goes to ~100 ns, realistically. Fair point. You can specify arbitrary fractions of a second in the timestamp passed to `--set`, but on my system, there's about 10 ms from `execve` to `clock_settime`. Variance isn't that high, but still at least 1-2 ms. @OP didn't really mention what precision is necessary, but given that the average dumb notebook quartz doesn't drift that much in a day, I guess shelling out is insufficient.

Comment: I suspect you'll see more variance in scenarios where the dentry and block caches aren't prepopulated with the executable and the libraries it requires. If they're hot, yes, things will be pretty consistent when not under load (a significant caveat itself).

Comment: I suspect that this is generally an issue? You'd also run into that problem if your `settime` call lives in a dynamic library, for example. So in any case, you might want to do this twice in a row.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You seem to be knowledgeable with timing issues. What kind of system clock precision can one realistically reach on a non-realtime concurrent execution system like linux? I read that PTP can go to microseconds, but I'm not sure I believe that…

Comment: You'd be surprised -- particularly with software built to calculate and correct for jitter over time, as ntpd is (this means that `ntpd` is much more accurate than `ntpdate` from the same codebase, as the latter runs a single retrieve-and-set operation). https://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo/#513-performance is dated -- but the age of that documentation makes the reported numbers all the more impressive.

Comment: (My own need for high-precision clocks has been in the context of building clustered/high-availability applications using single-writer resources, where we'd have a network power supply to kill any node that grabbed the shared resource and failed to give it up on schedule, and would have throughput starting to suffer at latencies well before that point; a few hundred milliseconds has been good enough in the real-world environments I've worked on, but more is of course better).